# How would I create a subset by matching multiple patterns at a specific location in column names?

Tags: r, subset, matching

Sample code using dput:

```
df <- structure(list
          (TCGA.OR.A5JP.01A = c(0.0980697379293791, NA, NA,0.883701102465278, 0.920634671107133), 
               TCGA.OR.A5JG.01A = c(0.909142796219422, NA, NA, 0.870551482839855, 0.9170243029211), 
               TCGA.PK.A5HB.01A = c(0.860316269591325, NA, NA, 0.283919878689488, 0.92350756003924), 
               TCGA.OR.A5JE.01A = c(0.288860652773179,NA, NA, 0.831906751819423, 0.913890036560933), 
               TCGA.OR.A5KU.01A = c(0.0897293436489091,NA, NA, 0.166760246036103, 0.920367435681197)), 
          row.names = c("cg00000029","cg00000108", "cg00000109", "cg00000165", "cg00000236"), 
          class = "data.frame")
```

I want to create a subset keeping columns which only contain certain patterns at positions 11 and 12 (I counted the "."s.). For example, the "x's" in TCGA.OR.A5xx.01A. I have a list of multiple codes/patterns for that position (e.g., "JG", "HB", "KU").

I have tried:

```
df_subset <- subset(df, select=grepl("JG|HB|KU",names(df)))
```

but it is not position specific and columns which coincidentally contain those patterns are included.

I also have a second question - can I somehow do this with a list of patterns? There are over 30 patterns I put in a list and I'm wondering if I could use that list instead of typing them all out again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use a combination of `str_locate` and `which` to select columns. If you have a list of search terms, then those can be collapsed into one list with `paste0`. Then, we can locate the search terms at particular positions (i.e., `11` and `12`), and select those columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

key_chr <- c("JG", "HB", "KU")
search_terms <- paste0(key_chr, collapse = "|")

df %>% 
  select(which(str_locate(names(df), search_terms)[,1] == 11 & str_locate(names(df), search_terms)[,2] == 12))
```

Or in base R, we could write it as:

```
df <- df[, which(regexpr(search_terms, names(df)) == 11)]
```

**Output**

```
           TCGA.OR.A5JG.01A TCGA.PK.A5HB.01A TCGA.OR.A5KU.01A
cg00000029        0.9091428        0.8603163       0.08972934
cg00000108               NA               NA               NA
cg00000109               NA               NA               NA
cg00000165        0.8705515        0.2839199       0.16676025
cg00000236        0.9170243        0.9235076       0.92036744
```

Comment: Using the base R method I end up with a list of what appears to be index positions?

Comment: @sumthymes I just reran it, and I do not get that. If you run only the interior part, then you would get index numbers, i.e., `which(regexpr(search_terms, names(df)) == 11)`. But putting it into the brackets, subsets the dataframe to just those column numbers.

Comment: Ah you are correct. When I read the .csv file in with my data the first column is the row names. I use `df <- data.frame(df, row.names = 1)` to set the row names and then it works. I don't know why it doesn't save the row names when I write.csv, but that's a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that does not relies on regex could be:

```r
subset(df, select = substring(names(df), 11,12) %in% c("JG", "HB", "KU"))

##>            TCGA.OR.A5JG.01A TCGA.PK.A5HB.01A TCGA.OR.A5KU.01A
##> cg00000029        0.9091428        0.8603163       0.08972934
##> cg00000108               NA               NA               NA
##> cg00000109               NA               NA               NA
##> cg00000165        0.8705515        0.2839199       0.16676025
##> cg00000236        0.9170243        0.9235076       0.92036744
```